# For results as one string

Tags: php

I am very new to coding, so sorry in advance for the noob question but I'm very stuck..

I have the following code here.

```
for($a = 1; $a < $arr; $a++) {
    $play['song_name'] = $count[$a]->trackName;    
    print '<div class="rocks">'.$a.'. '.$play['song_name'].'</div>';
}
```

Which returns the following output.

```
<div class="rocks">1. Journey (feat. Emotionz &amp; Gisto)</div>
<div class="rocks">2. Tupperware (feat. JFB)</div>
<div class="rocks">3. Stutter (feat. Naomi Rose &amp; Lil Cat)</div>
<div class="rocks">4. Feel the Rain (feat. Beardthug)</div>
```

Now I'm trying to add these data to WordPress using the following code.

```
for($a = 1; $a < $arr; $a++) {
    $play['song_name'] = $count[$a]->trackName;    
    $content = '<div class="rocks">'.$a.'. '.$play['song_name'].'</div>';

    $my_post = array(
        'ID'           => $post_id,
        'post_content' => $content,
    );
    wp_update_post( $my_post );
}
```

But in my WordPress it only returns this.

```
<div class="rocks">4. Feel the Rain (feat. Beardthug)</div>
```

How can I make it so that it will return my entire string?

Comment: at first glance, I think its because the `wp_update_post( $my_post );` method updates the so called "post" only with the last array ... in other words, in each iteration, you are **replacing** the "post" with a new array. Correct me if I am wrong. If I am right: consider pushing **all** data into an array.. then move the `wp_update_post` method outside of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with WP, but it looks as though you are merely updating a post - so logic tells me each update will override the previous, thus leaving only the last. Does it work to write them all together:

```
$content = "";
for($a = 1; $a < $arr; $a++) {
    $play['song_name'] = $count[$a]->trackName;    
    $content .= '<div class="rocks">'.$a.'. '.$play['song_name'].'</div>';
}

$my_post = array(
    'ID'           => $post_id,
    'post_content' => $content,
);
wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

Comment: I'm sad to say that this very simply fix solved my problem, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

With your current setup, you’re updating the same post for each iteration. Instead, you need to build up the string using concatenation:

```
$my_post = array(
    ‘ID’ => $post_id,
    ‘post_content’ => ‘’
);
for ($a = 1;  $a < $arr; $a++) {
    // setup your content string

    // concatenate with the . operator 
    $my_post[‘post_content’] .= $content
}
wp_update_post($my_post);
```

Comment: Just realised someone beat me to it. Sorry was typing on my phone 

Comment: Though the other persons answer helped me, I will probably be using something more along the lines of what you provided. I think it looks more professional.

Thanks for taking the time to help me with this problem Joe